# JSP - what's the difference between “<% … %>” VS “<%= … %>”

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, scriptlet

While working with `JSP` files and servlets , I came across  `<% … %>` and `<%= … %>` .

What's the difference between both cases ?

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html

Comment: you also have <!% ... %> in jsp, which are used for declaring your global variables

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I have seen `<%! &> but not <!% %> for method declaration.  Am I able to reverse the order?

Comment: @Mushy no no... just a typo, use <%!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`<%= … %>` will echo out a variable, where as `<% … %>` denotes a script or some code that is executed.

Here are the links to the jsp documentation:

- Expression (`<%= … %>`) : http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm4.html
- Scriptlet (`<% … %>`) : http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm5.html

Answer (score 11):

```
<%= new java.util.Date() %>
```

is same as

```
<% out.println(new java.util.Date()) %>
```

There are three types of Scriptlets :

- **Scriptlet Expressions of the form <%= expression %>** that are evaluated and inserted into the output
- **Scriptlet of the form <% code %>** that are inserted into the servlet's service method
- **Scriptlet Declarations of the form <%! code %>** that are inserted into the body of the servlet class, outside of any existing methods. For ex:

  ```
  <%!

  public int sum(int a, int b) {

  return a + b;
  }

  %>
  ```

Comment: what is the difference between `out.print()` and `out.println()`?

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya `out.print()` doesn't insert a new line escape sequence. `out.println()` does.

Answer (score 7):

In case of `<% ... %>` you are adding a server side code. And in case of `<%= ... %>` you are adding a server side code that automatically prints something. It could be seen as a shortcut for `<% out.print( something ) %>`.